# What should I do next to take care of this cactus which I grafted two years ago?

Tags: houseplants, cactus, grafting

Two years ago I succeeded in this grafting. I would like to know how long you think it will resist the cactus feeding the graft and what to do next?

[image]

Comment: Please post your questions in English. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's in a language other than English.

Comment: Please translate the title too.

Comment: Thanks for posting in English. However, I'm not sure what you're asking  - you appear to have grafted a cactus on top of a different cactus - are you asking if you can now separate them in some way? Also not sure what you mean by the cactus 'resisting' - if its like this now after two years, it looks as if the two co-exist very well.

Comment: Grafting *epihyillum* and *schlumbergia* hybrids onto a different cactus "rootstock" is a standard procedure, because the hybrids are chosen for their flowers and some only produce poor natural root systems. Grafting doesn't reduce the lifespan of the plants, but the rootstock cacti are not usually as big as the ones in the OP's picture so I suppose it is possible that those rootstocks might "reject" the grafted plant.

Comment: Welcome Florin C! I don't know your language, so I changed the title to match the question. I also put the picture into the question. I'm no expert, but it looks like a viable question now, so hopefully it will be re-opened for answers! As you know we are an English language site, but we still want to help! Our guidelines are explained in our [help]. [Ask] is a good place to start. Hopefully we can work together for your gardening needs!

Comment: Questions that are [on hold](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for a few days can get closed. You won't be notified if that happens, so please keep an eye on these! You can always edit them and try to re-open.